# Find a basis for the space $U = \{ x \in \mathbb R ^4 | (I − A)^2 x = 0 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For $v_1 = (-1, 0, 2, 1)$ and $v_2 = (0, 0, 0, 1)$ solve $(I-A)x=v$ and hence find a basis for the space 
$$
U = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^4 | (I-A)^2 x = 0 \}
$$
$$
A =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}\right).$$

I found the solution for $v_1$

$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-6 \\
1 \\
8 \\
0 \\
\end{array}\right)$+$t\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right)$

I'm not sure how to link $(I-A)x=v$ to $(I-A)^2 x = 0$ and find a basis for it.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: To start, you need better solutions for $v_1$ and $v_2$. You want to find *all* solutions to $(I-A)x=v$. Your solution for $v_1$ is trivial: find the  non-zero solutions as well. And find all other solutions for $v_2$. In both cases you will have a parameter, giving infinitely many solutions. Then continue from there.

Comment: Actually, what is that v? is it v_1 or v_2?

Comment: sorry that's for v_1

Answer (score 0):

the $v_1$  you have is in $\ker(A-I).$ you found $v_2 = (-6,1,8,0)^\top$ by solving $$(A-I)v_2 = v_1.$$  therefore $v_2 \in \ker(A-I)^2 \setminus \ker(A-I).$

by row reducing both $A-I$ and $(A-I)^2$ it can be verified that $$dim(\ker(A-I)) = 1,\,  dim(\ker(A-I)^2) = 1$$  basis for $$\ker(A-I) = span \{v_1\}, \ker((A-I)^2) = span\{v_1, v_2\}.$$